# Displacement map filter does not work on masked image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

here's my question.

I have an image with a size of 958*580. When I apply a displacement map filter to it, it works perfectly and the area I want to is affected accordingly. When I mask this image, so it only shows the area where the filter is supposed to act upon, nothing displays. The image is masked, but the area is no longer affected by the filter.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something about how the displacement map filter or the mask itself works, but I was hoping someone here could give me a pointer or two about what might be the issue here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say what has caused filter rendering issue, without seeing the code. I'have not met such behavior. Please try the code listed below, it should apply displacement filter to image and then mask it with circle-shape:

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.filters.DisplacementMapFilter;
import flash.geom.Point;

// image is taken form the Library, alternatively you may use Embed metatag
var imageBitmapdata:BitmapData=new imageBd() as BitmapData; 
var bitmap:Bitmap=new Bitmap(imageBitmapdata);
bitmap.width=stage.stageWidth;
bitmap.height=stage.stageHeight;


var maskCircle:Sprite=new Sprite();
maskCircle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF00FF, 1);
maskCircle.graphics.drawCircle(300,300,300);
maskCircle.graphics.endFill();


bitmap.filters=[getBitmapFilter()];
bitmap.mask=maskCircle;

addChild(bitmap);
addChild(maskCircle);


function getBitmapFilter():BitmapFilter {
    var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, true);
    bitmapData.perlinNoise(20, 20, 4, 12, true, true);
    var mapBitmap:BitmapData = bitmapData;
    return new DisplacementMapFilter(mapBitmap,new Point(0, 0),
                                 BitmapDataChannel.RED,
                                 BitmapDataChannel.RED,
                                 -20,
                                 -20,
                                 DisplacementMapFilterMode.CLAMP,
                                 0,
                                 0);
}
```